# Simultaneous usage of rule-based point displacement symbology and point clustering

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

I am trying to get three separate type of information across with one map. However it gets very cluttered with all of the points.

For example, one number I need is "Inspection", the second is "Treatment" and the third is "Sample", which will be in descending order since every point will count as an inspection, but not every inspection results in a treatment and not every treatment results in a sample.

I can get the individual counts for each category, but they all overlap each other and it cannot be read. If I use point displacement I get too many points in each circle.

Ideally I am looking to create a single point if its just inspections(ie. (5)), two points if there's inspections and treatments in an area side-by-side (i.e. (5)(3)) and a triangle pattern if there's inspections, treatments, and samples from an area (I.e (5)/(3)(2)).

Is this possible to do? It's sort of a combination of point displacement and point clustering but I cannot find a way to do it via that route.

Comment: Hi @Sean, if this answer solved your issue, accepting it as the right answer will help other's to finde help here, if they have the same issue. Otherwise, if you were after something different, it would also help to clearify this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly try this:

The trick would be to **not use symbology** but **use rule based Labels**

**1.** Go to the Lables Tab in the Layer Properties and choose `rule based labels`

**2.** Add a new Label with the "+" button on the bottom

**3.** Under **Labels** choose one of your categroies e.g. inspection

**4.** Under **Placement** choose `Offset from Point` and offset the point. If this turns out not to be enought use the Ofset X,Y option
[image]

**5.** repeate for the 2 other categories and choose different placements
[image]

########################################

**To match this with Symbology you can proceed as follows:**

**1.** Create a column which holds the information if there's just 1, 2 or all 3 categories being measured (1, 2, 3)

**2.** Go to the **Symbology** tab and choose `Point Cluster` and `Rule-based`, hit the `Render-Settings Option`

**3.** Similar like before: create 3 different symbols by **filter for the category** and make symbols with 1, 2 or 3 points. Use the ofset as described previously to position them.
[image]

**4.** your result should look a bit close to what you have described (if I interpret it correctly):
[image]